Wordpress Get next link among multiple custom post types
When i'm on a custom post type, i get the next link with this code:
function func_getnextlink() { 
    global $post;
    $html = '';
    
    $next_post = get_next_post();
    if($next_post) {
        $html .= '<a rel="next" class="next" href="' . get_permalink($next_post->ID) . '">NEXT</a>';
    }

    return $html;
} 

add_shortcode('getnextlink', 'func_getnextlink'); 

How can i get the next post, not looking to which post type i'm in?
I should be able to get the next link among two different custom post types.

You need custom query setting it to 'post_type' => 'any' set limit 'posts_per_page' => 1 and add date_query and look for next by date.

Add the following function in your active theme functions.php file
function get_next_post_any_type($current_post_id) {
    // Get the current post's publish date
    $current_post_date = get_post_field('post_date', $current_post_id);

    // Set up the query to find the next post across all post types
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'any', // Get any post type
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'orderby'        => 'date',
        'order'          => 'ASC',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'date_query'     => array(
            array(
                'after' => $current_post_date,
                'inclusive' => false,
            ),
        ),
    );

    // Execute the query
    $next_post_query = new WP_Query($args);

    // Return the post object if found
    if ($next_post_query->have_posts()) {
        $next_post_query->the_post();
        return get_post();
    }

    // Reset post data
    wp_reset_postdata();

    // Return null if no post is found
    return null;
}

How to use it
$current_post_id = get_the_ID();
$next_post = get_next_post_any_type($current_post_id);
if ($next_post) {
    echo 'Next Post Title: ' . $next_post->post_title;
    echo 'Next Post URL: ' . get_permalink($next_post->ID);
} else {
    echo 'No next post found.';
}

